# what's the main steps to handle a in app purchase content download

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my app i just want to add in app purchase, after user had paid,a package of videos and texts will be downloaded,i've followed the [in-app-purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) guideline and wrote some code that use can pay some money,but still don't know how to package my video and texts so that paid users can download the package,and the package can extract so that user can get the content inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through with this tutorial :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

It has everything you want to know about in app purchase with sample code and project.

I hope it will help you out..